# Salable quantity not updated after stock import in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, quantity, multi-source-inventory

I have **multiple websites** and each website have **single store** and a **single store view**.

Due to which I have multiple inventory tables created in database as

```
inventory_stock_1 (view)
inventory_stock_2 (table)
inventory_stock_3 (table)
```

When I upload stock for store #2 which is linked with table **inventory_stock_2**, table **inventory_source_item** gets updated with quantity mentioned in the csv file uploaded, but no entries are created in table **inventory_stock_2** for those products.

Because of this the products on that store #2 **(front end)** are shown in inconsistent state.

When I manually open the product in back end and save it without changing anything, the entry gets created in **inventory_stock_2** and product is shown properly on front end.

Is there anything to fix this issue?